# Export a constructor from a CommonJS style module in RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

I am attempting to export a constructor function using the `exports` object in a CommonJS style module. For some reason, requiring the module results in an empty object being returned instead of the exported function.

For example, this module;

```
define(function(require, exports) {
    var Example = function() {
        this.example = true;
    };

    exports = Example;
});
```

Results in a `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` error when it is required in another module and instantiated.

```
define(function(require, exports) {
    var Example = require('example');
    var example = new Example();
});
```

However, if I modify the module to return the constructor instead of using the exports object everything works as expected.

```
define(function(require, exports) {
    var Example = function() {
        this.example = true;
    };

    return Example;
});
```

Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like you would do in Node.js, you have to assign to `module.exports` rather than `exports` itself. So:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    var Example = function() {
        this.example = true;
    };

    module.exports = Example;
});
```

Assigning to `exports` cannot work because `exports` is a variable that is local to your function. There is no way for anything outside of the function to know that you've assigned to it. When you assign to `module.exports`. It is a different matter because you are modifying the *object* to which `module` refers.

The RequireJS documentation [suggests](http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html#exports) doing it like you did in your last snippet: just return the value you'd assign to `module.exports`.